# "Lick on a trick for a Rolex" — meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, lyrics

I heard this line in the rap song *Ghetto Bird* by Ice Cube ([full lyrics here](http://ohhla.com/anonymous/ice_cube/lethal/getobird.cub.txt)) and I'm completely puzzled by its meaning.

> My homey's here to **lick on a trick for a Rolex**
>   And let me try the four next
>   Now the four I was driving was hotter than July
>   looked up and didn't see it whippin' in the sky
>   Saw a chopper with numbers on the bottom
>   "Calling all cars, I think we've got em."

I learned that *lick* can mean ["easy money"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lick), and *a trick* can mean "a naive person", ["a sex act with a prostitute"](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/trick), or ["a robbery"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trick).

I could come up with several combinations of these meanings that would make sense on their own, but none of such combinations makes sense together with the following lines. Could somebody enlighten me what this line really means?

Comment: It's quite possible that there's a double meaning (or double entendre) here. Rap is full of wordplay.

Comment: I'm curious what "four" here is.

Comment: Literary interpretation/criticism, especially poetry and song lyrics, is off topic. There are no "right" answers, and "right" answers are the whole point of StackExchange.

Comment: @MετάEd
I'm not asking for criticism and I can hardly believe that these lines are deep or abstract enough that they cannot have "right" or even "wrong" interpretations.
The way I see it, the singer was describing a specific case of criminal activity that caused the use of helicopters by the police, unjustifiable from his point of view. The only thing preventing me from understanding the meaning is unfamiliar slang which should fall into the "green" "Word choice and usage" category from the FAQ.

Comment: There is actually a website devoted to deciphering rap lyrics --you'd probably have better luck there:  http://rapgenius.com/Ice-cube-ghetto-bird-lyrics

Comment: @ChrisSunami
Thank you for teaching how to fish! I did visit that site before I asked, but I thought the links lead to scammy malware-ridden sites selling random goods, so it didn't even occur to me to click one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Rapgenius](http://rapgenius.com/Ice-cube-ghetto-bird-lyrics#note-42725)** annotations:

**lick on a trick for a Rolex**    *rob a woman of her Rolex watch*

ALSO

**Now the four I was driving was hotter than july**

annotated: Ice Cube’s **1964 Chevy Impala** is wanted by the police

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the rap genius annotations, though "trick" may not refer to a woman in these lyrics. While "trick" usually refers to a female prostitute, Ice Cube may be using it here in the same way that rappers refer to other men as "bitches".  So my SAE translation...

```
My friend is here to rob this guy for his rolex.
```

A "four" is definitely a reference to a 64 chevy, the iconic old-school car for rappers.

Comment: I think you're right that the robbery victim is probably male. Trick doesn't really mean a prostitute though. A prostitute may "turn tricks". Perhaps here it means a client, otherwise known as a "john".